# ColdFusion 9 Solr: Can't create/update/refresh collections

Tags: coldfusion, solr, coldfusion-9

I've been having some issues with my Solr collections, and out of frustration I decided to delete all the folders and start from scratch.  I did not remove them via CFAdmin, first.

After some searching, I read where someone suggested copying the contents of the `/solr/core0` folder into the collections folders under `/ColdFusion9/collections`.  This will at least make them appear in CFAdmin.  However, when trying to index the collection(s), I get the following error:

```
ERROR unknown_field_author ERROR unknown_field_author request: 
    http:localhost:8983/solr/dtrparti/update?commit=true&waitFlush=false&waitSearcher=false&wt=javabin&version=1
```

Is this recoverable without having to re-install ColdFusion 9 from scratch?

Thank you,

^_^

Comment: As far as your salutation being removed, that is one of the "rules" here on stackoverflow.  See [the meta here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and [meta here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) for some references. Also try to post questions to the correct stackexchange site. There are a bunch. Scroll down the page to see links to them. I don't think they are trying to be rude but just trying to keep the clutter down. See the 'about' & 'faq' links at the top for info too

Comment: I knew about taglines.. but to remove salutations just seems.. pedantic.  IMHO.  RE: correct stackexchange site - I only use the stackoverflow.com site.. if there is a specific area of the site for ColdFusion, direct me to it, please.  BTW, I recognize you from other forums - glad to see you, here, and thanks for the (earlier) welcome!

Comment: You are on the correct site; stackoverflow.com is for programming questions. Just be sure to tag your ColdFusion questions with [tag:coldfusion] and/or any other appropriate tags.  Don't worry, there are a lot of helpful people here. And yes I recognize you as well.  Welcome!  Hope you get your solr issue(s) resolved. I don't know much about it unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry.. I should have posted the answer as an actual answer.. I will correct that, now.  I did (eventually) find the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

YES! IT IS! According to http://www.elliottsprehn.com/cfbugs/bugs/83331, if you add the following to all affected collection/conf/schema.xml:

<field name="author" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

.. it will now index.

^_^